# How to make SharePoint support MVC4 website

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, mvc

#### environment:

SharePoint 2016

Windows Server 2016

VS 2017

a  Mvc4 app (.net 4.6)

a junior programmer

#### aim

Let my MVC4 app be published to SharePoint like the SharePoint project,enabling it eo be built automatically when the management center migrates or creates a new server.

#### try

I found a solution on ths website:http://aspalliance.com/1944_using_aspnet_mvc_1_with_sharepoint_publishing.3

I tried replacing SPHttpApplication to register my route ,but always get [System.ArgumentExpetion:virtualPath] error;

**Can MVC be integrated with SharePoint,what should I do?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your actually calling `RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` from the `Application_Start` method in your inherited `SPHttpApplication` class (as per the example solution). And you will need to ensure you have setup the MVC routes accordingly.

Otherwise can I suggest having a look at the opens source [sharepointmvc](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sharepointmvc). Its quite old, but reviewing code and solution structure may be helpful as an end to end example and documentation.

**Overall I would reconsider the benefits of doing this**. The complexity introduced to your SharePoint Farm (i.e Patching, Migration, Solution conflicts, Support) is very large and I feel would more than likely outweigh the benefits.